# logging into a web site with urllib

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to login to a web site with urllib. This is an internal web site at my company.

The login page looks like this:

```
<form id="login" action="/accounts/login/" method="POST">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input name="username" type="text" class="text"><br>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input name="password" type="password" class="text"><br>
<input name="login_submit" type="submit" value="Sign in" class="submit">
```

My python looks like this:

```
url = 'http://10.188.36.250/accounts/login/'
values = {'user_name':'xxxx', 'password':'xxxxx'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url,data)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

I get back:

urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: FORBIDDEN

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're doing everything right, except using "user_name" as the key instead of "username".
Notice the form's variables.

Comment: Good catch, but I am still getting the 403.

Answer (score 1):

The default urllib2 open doesn't support cookies well.  it actually doesn't support anything well, it's a f(##$@# nightmare to work with.

To accomplish your task using urllib2, look into `urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()` and `urllib2.build_opener()`.  The former is passed into the latter, which you'll open pages with.  I don't recall exactly, but your code could look something like:

```
opener= urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor() )
req = urllib2.Request( url , data )
res = opener.open( req )
```

i'd also suggest looking at the `requests` module which makes doing internet-y things not suck so much in python ( http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html )

Comment: Your suggestion, using urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor() and urllib2.build_opener(), didn't help. I still got the 403. I did try the requests module - with that I did not get the 403, but I was not able to login - it just retuned the login page. Thanks just the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is all because you must use headers with your connect. Insert one of most popular web-browsers. in your headers. Mozilla - at least. Your code will look like -

```
req = urllib2.Request( url , data, headers=headers)
```

Where headers = `{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080201 Firefox/2.0.0.12'}`